# Android studio Login/Register ERROR

Tags: java, php, android

I've create an application LOGIN/REGISTER with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxffHgiJ64M&index=1&list=PLe60o7ed8E-TztoF2K3y4VdDgT6APZ0ka).

My problem is, if I put nothing on the register view of my app (name, username, age, password), it create an user on my table with nothing inside (just a number on "user_id" column) and I can sign in with nothing in "username" and "password" on the login view of my app.
And all my LOGIN/REGISTER android app becomes useless...

If you don't understand what I say, you can [try my app](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0dLG-pPxRMWUjZraFVyTTMwcGM).

**For information, I've change some element to not give you all access to my app :**

In "LoginRequest.class", I have change my website by xxx at this line :

```
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL ="http://xxxx.net/Login.php";
```

In "RegisterRequest.class", I have change my website by xxx at this line :

```
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL ="http://xxxx.net/Register.php";
```

In "Login.php", I have change my information at this line :

```
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql10.000host.com", "axxxxxxx_user", "passwordZ", "ayyyyyyy_data");
```

In "Register.php", I have change my information at this line :

```
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql10.000host.com", "axxxxxxx_user", "passwordZ", "ayyyyyyy_data");
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is **validations**

Put validation while registering and login. Don't call API if username, password and other fields are blank.

Comment: That is easy to bypass though, with a single space or a period or a random combination of letters

Comment: That depends on you whether you are omitting space or not, best practice is to trim your data before sending.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if user is entering a proper email-id , password should be more then 6 characters with combination of number and special character like stuff.

And in your server side do write procedures to validate the username or passwords.

You can also use an ORM which can protect you from injections.

Simple regex to vaid email-id would be

```
 /^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))$/iD
```